# Mocking Functions Using Python Mock

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to `Mock` a function (that returns some external content) using the python [mock module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

I'm having some trouble mocking functions that are imported into a module.

For example, in `util.py` I have

```
def get_content():
  return "stuff"
```

I want to mock `util.get_content` so that it returns something else.

I am trying this:

```
util.get_content=Mock(return_value="mocked stuff")
```

If `get_content` gets invoked inside another module, it never actually seems to return the mocked object. Am I missing something in terms of how to use `Mock`?

Note that if I invoke the following, things work correctly:

```
>>> util.get_content=Mock(return_value="mocked stuff")
>>> util.get_content()
"mocked stuff"
```

However, if `get_content` is called from inside another module, it invokes the original function instead of the mocked version:

```
>>> from mymodule import MyObj
>>> util.get_content=Mock(return_value="mocked stuff")
>>> m=MyObj()
>>> m.func()
"stuff"
```

Contents of `mymodule.py`

```
from util import get_content

class MyObj:    
    def func():
        get_content()
```

So I guess my question is - how do I get invoke the Mocked version of a function from inside a module that I call?

It appears that the `from module import function` may be to blame here, in that it doesn't point to the Mocked function.

Comment: I followed your exact description (in python 2.5, with mock 0.7.0, on linux), and it worked fine.  Do you have any more details that you can provide?

Comment: Hmm - it looks like the function behaves as expected when it is called from the top level scope. However, when it gets called from inside another module or function (i.e. further down the call stack) it doesn't exhibit the Mock-ed behavior. I am clarifying the example to illustrate this.

Comment: Okay, I tried your new description - I'm **still** getting the correct answer, even from `mymodule.func()`.  The only difference for me was that my `mymodule.func()` `return`s `util.get_content()`, and doesn't just call it.  I feel like there must still be some information missing in your description.  Have you actually tried your exact description above?  What is your *actual* code?

Comment: Sorry about that - I was avoiding having to paste large sections of code. You are correct - my reductive example doesn't quite fail, but I think I've partially figured out a solution. Will update this.

Comment: Strange - things aren't working right in my more complex Django test case, but when I try to distill it down the Mock object seems to be getting passed around as expected. I'm guessing there is some difference in the imports which is creating slightly different namespaces.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think I have a workaround, though it's still not quite clear on how to solve the general case

In `mymodule`, if I replace

```
from util import get_content

class MyObj:    
    def func():
        get_content()
```

with

```
import util

class MyObj:    
    def func():
        util.get_content()
```

The `Mock` seems to get invoked. It looks like the namespaces need to match (which makes sense). However, the weird thing is that I would expect

```
import mymodule
mymodule.get_content = mock.Mock(return_value="mocked stuff")
```

to do the trick in the original case where I am using the from/import syntax (which now pulls in `get_content` into `mymodule`). But this still refers to the unmocked `get_content`.

Turns out the namespace matters - just need to keep that in mind when writing your code.

Comment: I'd really love the answer for the general case. Sometimes `from util import get_context` syntax works with mocking and sometimes it doesn't. Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was very confused, why my mock worked in some files and not in others.

Comment: @johnboiles the answer to "why it works sometimes, sometimes not": The order of imports does matter here. If you mock gets executed before the import it works, if the import gets executed first, then it does not work.

Answer (score 68):

The general case would be to use `patch` from `mock`. Consider the following:

**utils.py**

```
def get_content():
    return 'stuff'
```

**mymodule.py**

```
from util import get_content


class MyClass(object):

    def func(self):
        return get_content()
```

**test.py**

```
import unittest

from mock import patch

from mymodule import MyClass

class Test(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('mymodule.get_content')
    def test_func(self, get_content_mock):
        get_content_mock.return_value = 'mocked stuff'

        my_class = MyClass()
        self.assertEqual(my_class.func(), 'mocked stuff')
        self.assertEqual(get_content_mock.call_count, 1)
        get_content_mock.assert_called_once()
```

Note how `get_content` is mocked, it is not `util.get_content`, rather `mymodule.get_content` since we are using it in `mymodule`.

Above has been tested with mock v2.0.0, nosetests v1.3.7 and python v2.7.9.

Comment: your comment on it being the module rather than the util helped me a lot!

Answer (score 29):

You have to patch the function where it is being used. In your case that would be in the mymodule module.

```
import mymodule
>>> mymodule.get_content = Mock(return_value="mocked stuff")
>>> m = mymodule.MyObj()
>>> m.func()
"mocked stuff"
```

There is a reference in the docs here: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Comment: What if we want to mock a built-in function like `open`?

Answer (score 12):

Let's assume you're creating your mock inside module `foobar`:

```
import util, mock
util.get_content = mock.Mock(return_value="mocked stuff")
```

If you import `mymodule` and call `util.get_content` without first importing `foobar`, your mock will not be installed:

```
import util
def func()
    print util.get_content()
func()
"stuff"
```

Instead:

```
import util
import foobar   # substitutes the mock
def func():
    print util.get_content()
func()
"mocked stuff"
```

Note that `foobar` can be imported from anywhere (module A imports B which imports foobar) as long as `foobar` is evaluated before `util.get_content` is called.

Answer (score 2):

While it doesn't provide an answer to your question directly, another possible alternative is to transform your function to a static method using the @staticmethod.

So you could transform your module utils into a class using something like:

```
class util(object):
     @staticmethod
     def get_content():
         return "stuff"
```

Then mock patches it correctly.