# Mocking functions with FlexMock in Python?

Tags: python, mocking

I know how to mock methods in Python using flexmock, like

```
 flexmock(subprocess).should_receive('call').replace_with(my_func)
```

How does one mock functions outside objects, or for example `glob`, which was imported via `from glob import glob` instead of `import glob`?

I have found [mocking functions using python mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286390/mocking-functions-using-python-mock) as a similar question, but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're importing the glob() function directly into the local namespace you have to get a handle on the current module.

```
from flexmock import flexmock
from glob import glob
import sys

flexmock(sys.modules[__name__]).should_receive('glob')
```

You could also do an "import glob as glob_module" or something along those lines to avoid the sys.modules lookup.