# py.test's monkeypatch.setattr(...) not working in some cases

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, monkeypatching

In **conftest** (in an autouse fixture):

```
monkeypatch.setattr('collector.util.download_data', lambda url:"Winning" )
```

In **collector/util.py**:

```
def download_data(url):
    assert False
```

In **the_caller.py**:

```
from collector.util import download_data
def some_function():
    download_data("blah")
```

When I call some_function(), I get the assert. However, if I change **the_caller.py** to:

```
import collector
def some_function():
    collector.util.download_data("blah")
```

then I get "Winning".

> Why is this behaving differently, and how can I make the monkeypatch
>   work for both scenarios?

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286390/mocking-functions-using-python-mock

Answer (score 17):

In general, it seems that the issue relates to how imports work in python. I'm not sure that there is a *good* solution.

The best work-around that I have found so far is the following:

```
monkeypatch.setattr('collector.util.download_data.__code__', replacement_function.__code__)
```

This works with both import types.
**One limitation is that this doesn't work with closures.**

---

This functionality can be added to the framework via:

```
from _pytest.monkeypatch import monkeypatch

monkeypatch.setcode = lambda self, func_str, replacement_func: \
    monkeypatch.setattr(self, func_str + ".__code__", replacement_func.__code__)
```

---

Reference: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pytest-dev/2013-October/002386.html

Comment: I think it's worth to note that that code up there is monkeypatching a monkeypatch library.

Comment: See [the unittest docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) for a good explanation of this.

Comment: Wow, I was deeply lost in an unpleasant monkeypatching rabbit hole, and this is the only thing that works. Unfortunately, understanding _why_ (it works) will need to wait for another day..

Comment: It turned out to be the only viable way to make monkeypatch work.